# SettingWithCopy Error While Using inplace=True

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting SettingWithCopy Warning while running the following code:

```
expNo = 1
file = pd.read_csv(file_name)
data = file[file['valid_data']==1]
data.rename(columns={'time':'delay'},inplace=True)
data['delay'].replace([199, 299, 399], [200, 300, 400], inplace=True)
data = data[['work','delay','answer','actual']]
if expNo == 1:
    data['prob'] = 50
if expNo ==2:
    data['prob'] = 75
```

prob is not a field in the csv file, so it's being appended to the file.

Can anyone please explain me what's wrong here? when I learned Pandas, I never got such errors.

Comment: What's `valid`?

Comment: Sorry, that's data, forgot to edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is this. First, you read your data into pandas DF called "file". Then you subset your "file" DF into "data" DF. Then you modify "data". The "data" DF is actually a view of "file" DF. So, you end up modifying a part of your "file" DF. One way to get rid of the warning is to append "copy" at the end of line 3:

```
data = file[file['valid_data']==1].copy()
```

This will create a "data" DF that's independent of "file" DF. As a minor nitpick, I'd suggest using more descriptive names for your DF's.

Self-contained fragments of code (much appreciated in future questions) are below:

```
import pandas as pd
file = pd.DataFrame([{'time': 199, 'work': 'a', 'answer': 'b', 'actual': 'a', 'valid_data': 1}, {'time': 299, 'work': 'a', 'answer': 'c', 'actual': 'a', 'valid_data': 0}, {'time': 300, 'work': 'a', 'answer': 'd', 'actual': 'a', 'valid_data': 1}])
data = file[file['valid_data']==1]
data.rename(columns={'time':'delay'}, inplace=True)
```

The above will give you a warning.

```
import pandas as pd
file = pd.DataFrame([{'time': 199, 'work': 'a', 'answer': 'b', 'actual': 'a', 'valid_data': 1}, {'time': 299, 'work': 'a', 'answer': 'c', 'actual': 'a', 'valid_data': 0}, {'time': 300, 'work': 'a', 'answer': 'd', 'actual': 'a', 'valid_data': 1}])
data = file[file['valid_data']==1].copy()
data.rename(columns={'time':'delay'}, inplace=True)
```

The above will not give you a warning.

Comment: Please double-check your code. Once I've added the .copy() in line 3, the warning disappeared.